# Static Data Member

Tags: c++

I couldn't understand the standard behavior at the code below. In my understanding, the static data member "a" must be constructed when variable "b" is created. It must be created only one time when b is constructed since it is a static data member. But somehow, compiler totally ignores class A and just writes "B's Constructor Called". I know that static data members must be declared within the class and they must be defined outside, and our static data member "a" is only declared, it is not defined. But why compiler doesn't generate an error message when it tries to create the static data member? It totally ignores Class A and even doesn't call A's constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
A()
{
  cout << "A's Constructor Called " << endl;
}
};

class B {
    static A a;

public:
    B()
    {
         cout << "B's Constructor Called " << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason that the message from `A`'s constructor never gets printed is because nothing in the shown code actually defines an instance of `A`. There is no object to construct, anywhere. You will notice the problem if `B`'s constructor tries to take an address of `a`. This code will result in a link error. Are you aware of the important difference between declaring and defining objects, in C++?

Comment: No, `static` members are not initialised when you create first member of the class that they are contained in. `static` members are initialised before `main` starts, when the (usually) out-of-class definition is encountered.

Comment: Btw, this is how `static` local variables in function work (i.e., `static` local variable in function gets initialised when the function is called for the first time), so I understand the confusion. `static` keyword is wildly overused in C++ and we didn't even get to linkage.

Comment: The code **declares** the static data member but doesn't **define** it. Add `A B::a;` to provide a definition. The original code didn't have a problem because it didn't use `B::a`.

Comment: Thank you all. I understood my confusion points. It is not static local variable in a function and static members are initialized before main starts. Sorry for that basic question but I'm still not clear why a is not created before the main? it has only declaration and doesn't have the definition. generally linker raises an error message when it can't find the definition but it doesn't create in that code.

Comment: Your code doesn't define `A` **and** doesn't reference `A`.  You will not get an "undefined reference" linker error because your code does not refer to that variable.  The linker never has to link to it.